# I want to use a $_SESSION variable in the quote function. I defined the $_SESSION variable in the login function. Login system works perfectly

Tags: php, mysql, sql, global-variables, session-variables

```
function loginUser($conn, $email, $password) {
    $managerExists = managerExists($conn, $email, $email);

    if ($managerExists === false) {
        header("location: ../login.php?error=incorrectlogin");
        exit();
    }

    $passwordHashed = $managerExists["password"];
    $checkPassword = password_verify($password, $passwordHashed);

    if ($checkPassword === false) {
        header("location: ../login.php?error=incorrectlogin");
        exit();
    }
    else if ($checkPassword === true) {
        session_start();
        $_SESSION["usersId"] = $managerExists["usersId"];
        $_SESSION["managerName"] = $managerExists["managerName"];
        header("location: ../dealerhome.php");
        exit();
    }
}
```

Quote Functions

```
function getQuote($conn, $plan, $years, $mileage, $deductible) {
    function getAgentPac($conn) {
        $sql = "SELECT pacAmount FROM `agent pac per dealer` WHERE managerName='Aiden'";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            return $row['pacAmount'];
        }
    }
    function getWarrantyCost($conn, $plan, $years, $mileage, $deductible) {
        $sql = "SELECT cost FROM `warranty costs pre pac` WHERE plan='$plan' AND years='$years' AND mileage='$mileage' AND deductible='$deductible'";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            return $row['cost'];
        }
    }
    echo getAgentPac($conn) + getWarrantyCost($conn, $plan, $years, $mileage, $deductible);
}
```

Comment: You just need to start the session and access the `$_SESSION` like you did in the other function.

Comment: Not related to your problem, but note that PHP doesn't support nested functions, so the functions "getAgentPac" and "getWarrantyCost" are both global functions, and if you run "getQuote" twice, you'll get an error because you're defining the same function twice.